# How can I compress a large collection of images together (for backup purposes) as densely as possible?

Tags: backup, compression, archiving

I have a fairly large (by personal use standards) collection of images. This is roughly in the range of 150k files of a total size of 200GB. It is by and large PNG and JPG files, each making up about half of the total file size. I would like to create a backup of this collection, and being a backup I want it to take up as little space as is feasible.

Ideally, I'd like to compress every image together into a single archive that is much smaller than the uncompressed total file size.

I'm willing to concede on (de)compression speed, to around the order of 12 hours either way. I am not willing to concede on image quality (however, maintaining the format is not important).

I've tried to mess with winrar & 7zip settings, but the compression ratio has generally turned out abysmal regardless. Trying google for help, it's difficult to find related questions that aren't talking about compression for web. Something more specialized than winrar/7zip would be more than welcome. I am on Windows, and anything I can run through WSL is welcome as well. I'm just not trying to spend money on more storage (right now).

I do not know what I can expect from a best-case scenario, if it's infeasible to get decent compression then so be it, but I'm hoping that by conceding on speed and file type, I can get a much better result than what I've tried.

Comment: jpg and png by default already have a high compression level, don't think you'll get much by trying to compress them.

Answer (score 1):

Winzip supports this in conjunction with their zipx format, all the way back in **2008**. [Source](https://www.winzip.com/static/wz/docs/wz-jpg-comp.pdf) and quote:

> The JPEG compression algorithm works by first unwinding this
> preexisting compression and then recompressing the file using an
> improved method that typically results in a 20-25% savings in space.
> **The algorithm is lossless and reversible**

In my own testing with the Winzip trial, I was able to reduce the size of a screenshot folder by exactly 20%, so their claims are right. So it does *not* have to be photos, but can be applied on jpg files in general. I have also tested this with the open source [zpaq](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html). Results in my case:

Folder of 4193 screenshots:

> original size: 981 MB

> zipx compressed: **775** MB

> zpaq (m5) compressed: 836 MB

Edit: When applying zpaq on the created zipx archive:

> zipx.zpaq (m5) compressed: 740 MB

Unfortunately this means the open source alternative isn't better here, however that has technical reasons too. Because to my knowledge, zpaq does not decompress jpegs to apply its own compression. It just compresses using its own methods right away.

However this approach can be also combined with [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) (also open source) - *if* you are willing to reencode images with a loss. I know you wrote you don't want this, I'm just mentioning this for completion.

In the past I used it to extremely compress old 8 megapixel phone images and used these additional command line arguments for convert.exe:

```
-sampling-factor 4:2:0 -auto-orient -quality 63 -interlace JPEG -colorspace sRGB -selective-blur 8x8+2% -define jpeg:dct-method=float
```

This brought me a saving of like ~80%, but there was visible gradient artifacts with skys and smooth surfaces. Please note the setting above is unsuitable for screenshots, as `-selective-blur` is then counterproductive. For phone images, this works pretty decent however.

Additional sources for reading: Peazip wiki for [zipx](https://peazip.github.io/zipx-file-format.html), [zpaq](https://peazip.github.io/paq-file-format.html)

Edit2: It is also noteworthy that the [JPEG XL](https://github.com/libjxl/libjxl) project exists. JPEGs can be **losslessly** converted into this format to make them smaller, similar to like Winzip does in their zipx archive. This can be a good choice if you are more tech-savy. An image viewer that currently supports this format is XnView MP.

Comment: Also I was barely able to hide my shock that 14 years later, people still didn't know about it. It is always important to have an open mind and evaluate the options that exist in the software world. Because, just because 7zip exists, doesn't mean that other solutions are useless (same with WinRar and the memes on the Internet)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, images are not compressible by 'normal' means. Zipping them will gain nothing & may even increase the size slightly.

Image compression is a highly specialised form of compression, & jpg/png etc are already about the 'best' they can be [to over-generalise a little]. You could perhaps gain a little by changing to a newer/better compression format such as HEIC.
JPG is lossy - ie, every time you compress & de-compress some information is actually thrown away forever.
PNG is lossless - ie, you can compress & de-compress repeatedly without losing any data.
HEIC is also lossy, but not as lossy as jpg & is a smaller file size for a given visual result. However, not all devices support it natively yet.

Comment: I'm aware of this personally, but my intuition (and hope) is that there is someone out there that has made a tool for this specific case. What I mean is that the images aren't just random truly uncompressible noise, and I would assume there could be some domain-specific compression for *sets* of images. This is opposed to the non-domain-specific compression of zipping and the (slightly, but sadly) wrong domain of single-image compression. Not that I'm expecting some magic bullet, but I have to assume it's theoretically possible to do better than what I have.

Comment: Nope. Images compress individually. Trying to do a bulk 'zip' just doesn't work. Consider them to be totally random data. [tbh, I don't know the low-level details of why, but as a photographer & cinematographer, I'm very much aware this is the case, no way round it except using HEIC/HEIV.] It has to be said, 200GB is really not much data these days. Some of my single images are in the GB range, as 16-bit TIFFs or PSDs. https://i.stack.imgur.com/stbgN.png

Comment: I'm aware of the high-level theory of compression, which is why my intuition is as I said it is. This is kind of talking past each other at this point, but consider near-duplicates. Testing it real quickly, 7zip does perfect duplicates well (of course, they're the same bytes), but shifting one by a few pixels messes it up entirely. We obviously know that if we could just say "take this one and shift it some pixels" it would do great. Simple example, but that's just the line of thinking here.

Comment: I think if it were possible, it would be common knowledge amongst film makers & photographers. That it isn't, very strongly hints that it is not possible.

Comment: You have a point, but I should point out that lossless video compression already does this in a more restricted domain. So the (theoretical) solution here is somewhere between, but whether it exists seems less than likely by this point.

Comment: Video uses keyframe & intermediates to calculate a difference between the last & next frame. You cannot do this with photographs.

Comment: Yeah, but this is what I meant with talking past each other. I'm just talking theory here. A video is (audio aside) a sequential collection of images, which I bring up as an example where good compression of a collection of images is *already being done* with the explicit caveat that it's a subset of my problem. I'm not saying it maps 1:1 or I'd just use video compression (which would be very funny if it worked). This just shows that there is *probably* a theoretical middleground somewhere between a video and literal separate images.

Comment: Yeah… but no, there isn't.

Comment: Zipping algorithms already can do slightly better than separate images (as they did when I tested here), which means there literally is some middleground right there.

Comment: Well… when you find it, let the world know. Until then, I'm done.

Comment: >> We obviously know that if we could just say "take this one and shift it some pixels" it would do great. Simple example, but that's just the line of thinking here.
In theory, applying delta compression to that series of images, assuming they're very similar, might give high compression rates w/o data loss, ASSUMING that the first image, the one the other similar ones are compared to, is present. If it were to be lost or become corrupted, the rest of the delta-compressed images would be nothing but trash. Which, apart from the computational overhead, is why nobody's doing it.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG uses lossy compression, and allows control of quality vs. file size. *If you're willing to lose some picture quality*, such as fine detail, use [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) (in batch mode),  or a [similar tool](https://alternativeto.net/software/irfanview/) to open each file (both PNG and JPEG) and then to save it as a JPEG of lower quality.

Another possibility would be to convert images to [HEIF](https://kinsta.com/blog/image-file-types/#7--heif--high-efficiency-image-file-format) format with a tools such as [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/). Theoretically, HEIF compression uses less space than JPEG.

In either case, test how the results look on a few files, and run a small batch, to check for additional needed space during conversion, before a massive change-over.

That said, I'd get an extra HDD (yes, not as fast as SSD, but, I believe, better for long-term storage). A 1 TB (5 times the space you've used) external HDD can be bought for less than $US40.

Comment: Sadly, keeping the image quality is very important in my case. It's basically just data hoarding, so keeping originals is pretty much the point. Hoping I don't have to resort to more storage, but if it comes to it then so be it!

Comment: Why not use HEIF, then, which claims to have much better compression than JPEG? Not sure if there would be any loss in quality - test.